# How to send form data to specific email?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have an `html form` and I would like to achieve two things with it:
1) - When user clicks on `"submit"` the data is automatically sent to a specific email and 2) - the user is redirected to a `"confirmation page"`. I do not want to use `mailto` function as it is pretty bad since its browser dependent. I would like to use a light script... Is it possible using js?

Comment: *short answer*: no, it is not possible using only js. you need a server side language to send the message. javascript can tell the server to send a message via a form submit or ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with JavaScript alone.

---

What you *can* do is use AJAX to send your form data to a server-side script which will send your email, then the AJAX success handler can redirect the page to some confirmation page.

Some hosts have email scripts installed, like CGI scripts, to handle sending email for you on the server side.

This is essentially the best you can do on the client side (using jQuery for ease):

```
var data = {
    name: $("#form_name").val(),
    email: $("#form_email").val(),
    message: $("#msg_text").val()
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        // Redirection on success
        var url = "http://example.com/confirmation.html";    
        $(location).attr('href',url);
    }
});
```

and the essential server-side script:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Input sanitation omitted

    // Send the email
    mail("my.email@gmail.com", "Message from {$name} - {$email}", $message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible in pure JavaScript.